# Swift Core Data - _NSSingleObjectI (capital "i" at the end) being returned instead of String

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to display the city name of an address that's related to a place in core data, but it looks like a Set is being returned instead of a String. For example, for a city name, this:

```
 {( 
   Houston
 })
```

is being printed instead of just "Houston"

An Address to a Contact (contact is what I'm naming a "place") has a "To One" relationship, and Contact has a "To Many" relationship to Address.

The following shows how I am saving the objects & relation to core data:

```
    //creating contact managed object context
    let contact: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    contact.setValue(self.name, forKey: "name")

    //setting up address object for relation
    for address in self.addresses {
        let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Address", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        print(address.city) //prints fine without the brackets, i.e. just "Houston"
        object.setValue(address.id, forKey: "id")
        object.setValue(address.city, forKey: "city")

        //creating relationship between address object and contact
        contact.mutableSetValueForKey("addresses").addObject(object)
    }

     do {
        //saves the contact object
        try contact.managedObjectContext?.save()
        return true;
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
```

Then in my view controller, I'm using this to display the relation.

```
 let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "contactType = %@", "place")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        if results.count != 0 {
            for result in results {
                if let address = result.valueForKeyPath("addresses.street1") {
                    print(address) //where the {( "Houston" }) formatting is occurring
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Couldn't fetch core data")
    }
```

Comment: I would also like to add that doing print(String(address)) returns the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - because the `address` relationship is to-many, it is represented by CoreData as a `NSSet` (or sometimes `NSOrderedSet`).  Even if in fact there is only one `address`, it's still represented as an `NSSet` with only one element.

When `valueForKeyPath` is used with an `NSSet`, it returns a new `NSSet`, created by passing the same `valueForKeyPath` call to each object in the set.  So:

```
if let address = result.valueForKeyPath("addresses.street1") ....
```

returns an `NSSet` made up from the `street1` attributes of each `Address` in the set.

If there can be only one `Address` for each `Contact`, you should amend your relationship to be to-one (and amend/regenerate the subclass accordingly).

But if you do want to have many `Addresses` for each `Contact`, you need to decide how you will deal with them: eg. enumerate the set, convert it into an array, take only one value and ignore the others, etc.

```
// enumerate...
for eachAddress in address { ... }
// convert to array
let arrayOfAddresses = address.allObjects
// use any element
let anyAddress = address.anyObject()
```